# How to hide VSCode "Publish changes" action button from source control tab

Tags: visual-studio-code

Recently introduced in VSCode, how can I prevent this sync button from showing ?

[image: publish changes button]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The related release note
https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_61#_publish-or-sync-action-button-for-git-repositories

```json
// settings.json

{
  "git.showUnpublishedCommitsButton": "never",
}
```

Answer (score 5):

This setting worked for me.
Found it [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_61#_sourcecontrolactionbutton).

```
  "git.showActionButton": {
    "commit": false,
    "publish": false,
    "sync": false
  }
```